# Creating a command in a bundle to do a find in a replace in a given document

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

I'm looking to create a command in a textmate bundle that when run will:

1. Search the document for a given string
2. Replace that string with another given string

The strings will always be the same

Search for 
    `<?` 
replace with 
    `<?php`

I know I can use textmate's find and replace functionality - I'm just trying to automate a little.

This should only make changes on the current page, not the entire project.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a [Macro](http://manual.macromates.com/en/macros#macros).

Simply go to `Bundles -> Macros -> Start Recording`, and then execute your Find and Replace as you wish it saved.  Stop and Save the recording, and then you can assign it a command in the Bundle Editor.

Comment: Awesome...thanks.  I had gone the route of writing a script that I called from a command but this is much easier.